# Excel Formula to sum the values from one column only if there are values in another column?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sum

This is hard for me to explain and I'm not an expert.  Sorry if this is confusing.

I have a worksheet that lists several items a customer could buy and I need the worksheet to create price and cost totals depending on what items they select. I have the price total but having issues with the costs because I only need the sum of the costs for items that have a price in the respective cell.

Below is a small sample of my table.  Basically, I need a formula to sum up the cost (column B) if there is a price in Column C.

I started doing this but the string would be insanely long:  `IF(C2<>"",B2,0)+IF(C3<>"",B3,0)+...`  Is there a formula to make this work for several rows together?

[See sample here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdz8p.png)

If you recommend doing something completely differently, I'd love any suggestions.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have a look at `SUMIFS`

Comment: YES!!!!  Thank you.  This formula worked: `=SUMIFS(B2:B100,C2:C100,">0")`